# Doubled form validation button (iOS)

Tags: forms, buttons, ios, validation, confirmation

I have asked myself this question a few times lately.

Should I put a validation button at the right-hand corner of the header and another at the bottom of the form ?
The right-hand button is useful when the keyboard is open, but is not very visible and does not give the impression of a principal button. While the bottom button is pretty clear and reminds of a website interface, but  is not visible while the keyboard is open.

I often see both cases.
So, is it really disturbing to put two confirmation button ? Or should I make a choice taking into account the amount of form fields that open the keyboard ?

Thanks you by advances.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using the same button twice in a layout. Adapt to the platform ([iOS in this case](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/buttons/)) common pattern if there is no preference.

**Don't make the user think**. When some of your users see both buttons it will create them confusion "Is this button the same one as the other? Do both perform the same action?" Even if they ignore these doubts or are sure of the answer and continue you should try to avoid the question in the first place.